# How to decorate Always-on-top windows?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

The idea is exactly as in the title.
Coming back to Ubuntu after a couple of years using Windows, I really enjoyed the way Always on top PowerToy [emphasizes said windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/always-on-top).

[image: image showing always on top window decorated]

Is there a way to achieve this with Ubuntu? My search has been unfruitful so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can get half way there. By "half way" I mean that there is a way to have the top window highlighted, but not the "always on top" window only.

If you are interested in that, install the [Tiling Assistant](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3733/tiling-assistant/) extension. I recommend installing it using the Extension Manager, which you can install by opening a terminal and running this command:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```

After installing Extension Manager do the following:

1. Open Extension Manager and click the *Browse* tab.
2. Search for "tiling assistant" and click *Install* to install the extension (I have already installed it in the screenshot):

   [image: Extension Manager - Search]
3. Go to the *Installed* tab and press the cog button next to *Tiling Assistant* to open the extension's settings:

   [image: Extension Manager - Installed extensions]
4. In the window that opens, scroll to *Active Window Hint* and select *Always*:

   [image: Tiling Assistant settings]
5. Now your top window will have a border as shown in the screenshot below:

   [image: Calculator window with border around it]

   You can further customize the appearance of the border through the extension's settings.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I already use this extension, but versions above 36 (the one I have) are not compatible with Gnome 42.5, the version Ubuntu22.04 sports. I force-installed the updated version from the sources, but the feature is _only_ to highlight the focused window. so it does not really achieve the researched goal here. Sorry.